# Android View Binding - Unresolved Reference in Multi Module Project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

## Issue

The *[Crypto Tweets](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/CryptoTweets)* sample app `root` branch implements *[Android View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)* for each of the three app modules, `app`, `app-rx`, and `app-simple`. All three modules run as expected. However, in the `app` and `app-rx` module, there are Lint errors for `Unresolved reference`.

For example, in the `app` and `app-rx` modules the `fragment_feed.xml` is unresolved whereas in `app-simple`, the reference shows no import error.

An IssueTracker *[bug has been filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176215130)*. Please star the issue in order to raise its' awareness.

## Configuration

- Android Studio 4.1.1
- Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 4, 2020
- Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS 10.16
- GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
- Memory: 1979M
- Cores: 16
- Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
- Non-Bundled Plugins: com.android.tool.sizereduction.plugin, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, cn.wjdghd.unique.plugin.id, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, com.developerphil.adbidea, com.google.mad-scorecard

## Architecture

*settings.gradle*

```
rootProject.name='CryptoTweets'
include ':app', ':app-rx', ':app-simple'
```

*Project navigation view*

- `app`: *CryptoTweets* > *app* > *src* > *main* > *java* > *app* > *cryptotweets* > *feed* > *FeedFragment*
- `app-rx`: *CryptoTweets* > *app-rx* > *src* > *main* > *java* > *app* > *cryptotweets* > *feed* > *FeedFragment*
- `app-simple`: *CryptoTweets* > *app-simple* > *src* > *main* > *java* > *app* > *cryptotweets* > *feed* > *FeedFragment*

## Implementation

*build.gradle* (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.gradle_version = '4.1.1'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    ext.kotlin_coroutines_version = '1.3.9'
    ext.appcompat = '1.2.0'
    ext.legacy_support = '1.0.0'
    ext.core_ktx = '1.3.2'
    ext.constraint_layout = '2.0.4'
    ext.navigation_version = '2.3.2'
    ext.navigation_safe_args_version = '2.3.1'
    ext.dagger_version = '2.28.1'
    ext.retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
    ext.lifecycle_livedata_ktx = '2.2.0'
    ext.room_version = '2.2.5'
    ext.room_alpha_version = '2.3.0-alpha03'
    ext.paging_version = '2.1.2'
    ext.paging_version_alpha = '3.0.0-alpha10'
    ext.coil_version = '0.13.0'
    ext.glide_version = '4.11.0'
    ext.junit = '4.13.1'
    ext.androidx_junit = '1.1.2'
    ext.espresso_core = '3.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_safe_args_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### `app-simple`

This module does not contain the View Binding Lint errors for `Unresolved reference` in the `FeedFragment.kt` for `FragmentFeedBinding`.

*build.gradle (:app-simple)*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.cryptotweets"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions { targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'

    buildFeatures.viewBinding = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.21"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha10"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:0.13.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

*FeedFragment.kt*

```
package app.cryptotweets.feed

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import app.cryptotweets.R
import app.cryptotweets.databinding.FragmentFeedBinding
import app.cryptotweets.feed.adapter.FeedAdapter

class FeedFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_feed) {

    private val viewModel: FeedViewModel by viewModels()
    lateinit var adapter: FeedAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // The View Binding reference for 'FragmentFeedBinding' imports as expected.
        val binding = FragmentFeedBinding.bind(view)
        initViewStates(binding)
    }
}
```

### `app`

This module contains the View Binding Lint errors for `Unresolved reference` in the `FeedFragment.kt` for `FragmentFeedBinding`.

*build.gradle (:app)*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.cryptotweets"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions { targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'

    buildFeatures.viewBinding = true

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$legacy_support"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_ktx"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_layout"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_livedata_ktx"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_alpha_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_alpha_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_alpha_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version_alpha"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:$coil_version"

    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidx_junit"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_core"
}
```

*FeedFragment.kt*

```
package app.cryptotweets.feed

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import app.cryptotweets.R
import app.cryptotweets.databinding.FragmentFeedBinding
...

class FeedFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_feed) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Fixme: Unresolved reference for 'FragmentFeedBinding'
        val binding = FragmentFeedBinding.bind(view)
        initViewStates(binding)
    }
}
```

### `app-rx`

This module contains the View Binding Lint errors for `Unresolved reference` in the `FeedFragment.kt` for `FragmentFeedBinding`.

*build.gradle (:app-rx)*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = '1.8' }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.cryptotweets"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions { targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

    buildFeatures.viewBinding = true

}

dependencies {
    def rx_version = '3.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$legacy_support"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_ktx"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_layout"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_livedata_ktx"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_alpha_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_alpha_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_alpha_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-rxjava2-ktx:$paging_version"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:$coil_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:$rx_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:$rx_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:$retrofit_version"

    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidx_junit"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_core"
}
```

*FeedFragment.kt*

```
package app.cryptotweets.feed


import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import app.cryptotweets.R
import app.cryptotweets.databinding.FragmentFeedBinding
...

class FeedFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_feed) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Fixme: Unresolved reference for 'FragmentFeedBinding'
        val binding = FragmentFeedBinding.bind(view)
        viewModel.launchViewEvents(this)
        initViewStates(binding)
    }

}
```

## Attempted Solutions

1. *File* > *Sync Project with Gradle Files*
2. *Build* > *Clean Project*
3. *Build* > *Rebuild Project*
4. *[Clear the build cache](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache#clear_the_build_cache)*
5. *File* > *Invalidate Caches / Restart…*
6. Update dependency library versions.
7. Re-clone the *[Crypto Tweets](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/CryptoTweets)* sample app repository from GitHub.

Comment: hi, did you find solution?

Comment: I have not. Please refer to the Google bug link above that has been filed above for updates.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, added

```xml
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:1.2.1"
```

to `module` Gradle file and the error on
`import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidViewBinding` disappeared

Answer (score 0):

It will surely be late, but just in case anyone else is facing the same issue, this is how I fixed it:

In my specific case, I had the next implementation in the module Gradle file:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

and after changing to a Kotlin specific version like this:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0"
```

The "Unresolved reference" build error has gone.